# The influence of the second catilinarian conspiracy on the fall of the Roman Republic?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-republic

When studying Roman history during the first century BC, one of the prominent events mentioned is the second Catilinarian conspiracy, wherein Catiline seeks to overthrow the Roman Republic through a scheme but is prevented by Cicero, who denounced Catiline through his four orations and eventually executes five members of Catiline's conspiracy without due process. Was this event a symptom of the political instability during the 60s BC in Rome, or was this an event a cause of political instability (cause vs symptom)? How influential was this event in the fall of the Roman Republic?

Comment: Is there a reason to think it caused the instability? There were multiple civil wars in the preceding decades. Actually, Rome is generally thought to have went through an extended period of political stability for a century or so, with the Catiline Conspiracy much nearer the end.

Comment: The instability is generally thought to have been initiated in 133 BC by Tiberius Gracchus's land bill and his subsequent murder, and the instability is thought to have ended in 27 BC with the establishment of the Augustan principate. There were many civil wars, and thus many factors. I am just wondering if the conspiracy was a factor, or just coincidentally occured along with all the civil wars @Semaphore

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it solicits theories.

Comment: This question doesn't solicit theories. All I am asking is for the big picture significance of the second catilinarian conspiracy in the context of the fall of the roman republic. @TylerDurden

Comment: @TylerDurden I think it's implicit in posting here that the theories should be historical, scholarly theories. Save your criticism for bad answers, if they ever even arrive.

Comment: It was more a symptom of Cicero's puffing up a joke of a plot into something major to cement his consulship as something important.

Comment: So the second catilinarian conspiracy is really unimportant, but Cicero made a big deal out of it to further his political career? Thanks @Oldcat

Comment: Just look at the haul - Catiline fled early, joined an army that he didn't form that was already in revolt.  Then five other guys are rounded up and lynched.  Compare that to the pogroms against the Gracchi, where dozens to thousands were killed, not to mention the actual civil wars before and after this event.